# Can someone explain this recursive function? I understand how this function counts down to zero, but not how it counts back up to num1?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def print_num_pattern(num1,num2): 

    if (num1 == 0 or num1 < 0): 
        print(num1, end = ' ') 
        return

    print(num1, end = ' ') 
    print_num_pattern(num1 - num2, num2) 

    print(num1, end = ' ')
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your code, see what gets printed by each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's not actually "counting back up". Observe the following:

print_num_pattern(10, 4)

```
10 (chunk) 10
```

then it becomes

```
10 6 (chunk2) 6 10
```

after reducing 10 by 4. Then repeat it on 6 and so forth. Make sense?

The key thing to note is that

```
    print(num1, end = ' ')  # < --- 
    print_num_pattern(num1 - num2, num2) 
    print(num1, end = ' ') # < ---
```

the sections with the `# < ---`  actually output the same value